# Jquery Validation is not working for dynamic controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I need to use jquery validation for dynamic controls. I tried but i was unable to achieve it. Help me on this issue.

**Views:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var count = 0;
        $("#dynamicControlForm").validate();
        $("#AddControls").click(function () {
            count++;
            var elements = "<input type='text' id='txt" + count + "'class='rec'/><br/></br>";
            $(elements).appendTo("#dynamicControlForm");
            $(".rec").each(function () {
               $(this).rules("add", {
                required: true,
                messages: {
                    required: "Required field"
                }
            });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="DynamicControlsContainer">
    <input type="button" name="CreateControl" value="AddControl" id="AddControls" />
    <form action="/" method="post" id="dynamicControlForm">
    <input type="submit" name="DynamicControl" id="btnDynamicSubmit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very close.

However, the `name` attribute is missing from your dynamically created `input` elements.

The jQuery Validate plugin requires that all data input elements to be validated **must** each have a unique `name` attribute.

This works...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var count = 0;
        $("#dynamicControlForm").validate();
        $("#AddControls").click(function () {
            count++;
            var elements = "<input type='text' id='txt" + count + "' name='txt" + count + "' class='rec'/><br/></br>";
            $(elements).appendTo("#dynamicControlForm");
            $(".rec").each(function () {
                $(this).rules("add", {
                    required: true,
                    messages: {
                        required: "Required field"
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });

});
```

**Working DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/sVFgK/